# How to let Google bot know we are the creators of a well reviewed Amazon product?

Tags: seo, schema.org, markup, amazon

We are the manufacturers and only sellers of a popular product on Amazon which has about 500 reviews, averaging about 4.5 stars. We have just launched a website for the product. Is there a way to let Google's search bot know that we are the creators of this well reviewed product and as such give us a boost in the search rankings?

The only options I can see is: use schema Product markup to markup up the product pages with Review tags that specify Amazon is an organisation that has given us an aggregate review score of 4.5. I'm not sure if this is abusing the review tag though.

Would this help? If not, what other options are there?

Answer (score 1):

Interlinking.

Google's original (and current) algorithm is based on links, I often explain it like this:

Let's say that your website has a link from a webpage like `ohio.gov/insurance/vendors/licensed-agencies/county/cuyahoga`, without me listing the destination of the link, the anchor text of the link, or anything else, can you guess what line of business that company is in?

I have a pretty good guess.

Link your Amazon store to your website and your website to your Amazon store (even if you can't create a hyperlink, include the text), and maybe share both from the same social media accounts.

Schema.org markup can't hurt but in a case like yours, I suspect Google will ignore it if other things don't support it.

Have you set up Google+ profiles and `rel=author` and `rel=publisher` links?

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Schema Product markup will definitely help in your case while i suggest to you that go with Google Help Page - [About unique product identifiers](https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/160161?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks. Would I also tag that e.g. the Amazon organisation has given an aggregated review of 4.5 for the product though or is that misusing the tagging? Intuitively, you'd think the homepage for a product would be an authoritative source for people searching about that product but only marking up the product does nothing to separate our site from anyone else selling it.